# Jasmine/PhantomJs spec runner

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, phantomjs, gulp

I cannot get my test to run using phantomJs.

**gulp task**

```js
var jasminePhantomJs = require('gulp-jasmine2-phantomjs');
gulp.task('test', function() {
    return gulp.src('./SpecRunner.html')
        .pipe(jasminePhantomJs());
});
```

**SpecRunner.html**

```html
<script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/lodash.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/boot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine-jquery.js"></script>

<!-- include source files here... -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/exportToCsv.js"></script>

<!-- include spec files here... -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="spec/exportToCsvSpec.js"></script>
```

Running this file standalone reports all my tests in `exportToCsvSpec` to be passing. However, when I attempt to run my gulp task I get the following:

```
Using gulpfile ~/gulpfile.js
Starting 'test'...
Start running spec file:  /ExportToCsv/SpecRunner.html
PhantomJS path:  /ExportToCsv/node_modules/gulp-jasmine2-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs
Loading /ExportToCsv/SpecRunner.html
Page has timed out; aborting.

gulp-jasmine2-phantomjs: ✖ Assertions failed in SpecRunner.html
'test' errored after 31 s
Error in plugin 'gulp-jasmine2-phantomjs'
Command failed:
```

While I'm not familiar with this exact gulp plugin I am not new to `phantom`. I can't seem to figure out why it's failing.

The code is located here if you'd like to play with it [Linky](https://github.com/MikeFielden/ExportToCsv)
CI is located here for those interested as well [Other Linky](https://travis-ci.org/MikeFielden/ExportToCsv)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed this problem.  In the gulp plugin `gulp-jasmine2-phantomjs` in mentions a requirement of `jasmine2-junit` which I had but what I did not have was the updated `boot.js` file that `jasmine2-junit` requires.

[From the jasmine2-junit repo](https://github.com/sandermak/jasmine2-junit)

> Note that the boot.js file is a modified version of the file with same
>   name that is provided by the default Jasmine 2.0 distribution. The
>   only modification is that the JUnitXmlReporter is added as reporter.
>   Currently, it seems impossible to add a reporter while still using the
>   stock boot.js.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/MikeFielden/ExportToCsv/commit/98cacc95c374ed75c985857993f678fcb3ba62de#diff-2555fbe803726c4944ca579ef44d56f6) the change was only a couple lines added to the `boot.js` file.